# Different behavior for unique_ptr with move?

Tags: c++, move, unique-ptr

I have code as following

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(0));
std::unique_ptr<int>& b = a;
v.insert(v.begin(), std::move(b)); //ok
```

However if I add const in the third statement

```
const std::unique_ptr<int>& b = a;
v.insert(v.begin(), std::move(b)); //Compiler error, cannot access ptr private member
```

Why does the compiler show it cannot access private member of the unique pointer other than cannot convert const to non-const?  Thanks.

Comment: Why "why"? Why not!? If the thing is const, you can hardly expect to be able to mutate it...

Comment: @chris Without the `move` calls the code will *attempt* a copy and fail to compile, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: indeed it will not compile, but you can't move a `const` object. Moving is altering state, and `const` is forbidding that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Never mind. That's only for rvalues that I was thinking of, and this code inserts a named object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move a `const` object. Moving means **altering the state** of the object you moved from (of whatever type that object is), and declaring it as `const` makes a promise that you won't alter that state. Thus, moving a `const` object is a contradiction in terms.

Although the expectation of being able to move a `const` object may indeed have some kind of justification (for instance, you may want the object to be `const` *as long as you use it*, and then get rid of it when you're done and *transfer* its guts rather than copying it - which is btw impossible with a `unique_ptr`), actually allowing this would have a number of very impractical semantic consequences (for instance, it would allow *swapping* two `const` objects).

Thus, even though the language does technically allow moving from a `const` object (move constructors accepting a `const` RRef are *legal*), no type of the Standard Library actually gives you that possibility, including `unique_ptr`, and you should not write any UDT that does.

Conceptually, it is really important to think of moving as a **state-altering operation**, which is *not* compatible with the `const` modifier.